# Tengo problemas con un select

Tags: jquery

estoy tratando de mostrar 2 div que se encuentran oculto. La idea es que cuando presione una de las opciones del select, se muestre su respectivo div. En este momento el código que tiene que ver con el select, no está funcionando. Yo no tengo ni la menor idea de cómo se podrá hacer ésto. Lo que tengo implementado es sin saber si es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
Este es el select que debe lanzar los div ocultos.
... 
     <div class="form-group" id="ajuste">
            <label for="nivel" >Categoria</label>
            <select name="categoria" class="form-control" id="categoria">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
                <option value="1">Estudiante</option>
                <option value="1">Trabajador</option>
            </select> 
             <div class="ayuda">
                <p> Si selecciona Estudiante, debera mosrar los grupos, en caso contrario los dpto.</p>
            </div>          
        </div>
...
```

Estos son los div ocultos.

```
...
        <div class="form-group oculto" id="grupoContenedor">
            <label for="grupo" >Grupo</label>
            <select name="grupo" class="form-control" id="grupo">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
                <option value="1">1301</option>   
                <option value="2">1302</option>
                <option value="3">1303</option>   
                <option value="4">1304</option>
                <option value="5">1305</option>   
                <option value="6">CPE</option>
            </select>  
            <div class="ayuda">
                <p> Solo se muestra si se selecciona estudiante.</p>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group oculto" id="dptoContenedor">
            <label for="dpto" >Dpto.</label>
            <select name="dpto" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
                <option value="1">Programación</option>   
                <option value="2">Humanidades</option>
                <option value="3">Ciencias Básicas</option>   
            </select>    
            <div class="ayuda">
                <p> Solo se muestra si se selecciona trabajador.</p>
            </div>              
        </div>
...
```

Código en jQuery:

```
...
    $("#categoria").click(function(){

        if ($("#categoria").val() == 1) {
            $("#grupoContenedor").show(500);
        }

        if ($("#categoria").val() == 2) {
            $("#dptoContenedor").show(500);
        }

        /*var categoria = $("#categoria").val();
        switch(categoria){
            case 1: $("#grupoContenedor").show(500);
                    break;
            case 2: $("#dptoContenedor").show(500); 
                    break;
            default:$("#grupoContenedor").hide(500);
                    $("#dptoContenedor").hide(500); 
                    break;  
        }*/

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

en jquery existe una función que escucha cuando un elemento en especifico del DOM cambia de valor. Te dejo un enlace para que lo revises:https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-change-1879/

Aquí la solución:

```js
//Escuchas cuando este elemento cambia de valor
$("#categoria").change(function(){
    //Obtiener el valor seleccionado
    var catSeleccionado = $("#categoria").val();
    if(catSeleccionado == 1){
        $("#grupoContenedor").show();
    }
    //OTRAS CONDICIONES
    //...
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No tenía idea que existiera ese método. Yo m estaba volviendo loco pq no sabía cómo implementar eso. Gracias a ambos x echarme una mano.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un par de cosas por las que no te sale:

1. Un despiste en el valor del tercer option en el select original. Ambos *values* tienen el mismo valor (1).
2. Has utilizado el evento o método *click* para activar el evento sobre tu select original; sin embargo el método *click* no es el que te interesa, ya que se va a activar cuando el usuario haga click con el ratón sobre tu select. Es decir, el evento se activará en cuanto se despliega el select con los valores (momento en el que el usuario aún no habrá escogido ninguna opción porque acaba de desplegar/abrir el select).

Lo que debes utilizar en este caso es el evento *change*. Este evento se activará cuando el usuario cambie el valor del select: es decir, cuando haga click sobre el option adecuado.

```js
$("#categoria").change(function(){

    //$('.oculto').hide();

    if ($("#categoria").val() == 1) {
        $("#grupoContenedor").show(500);
    }

    if ($("#categoria").val() == 2) {
        $("#dptoContenedor").show(500);
    }
});
```

```css
.oculto {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="ajuste">
    <label for="nivel" >Categoria</label>
    <select name="categoria" class="form-control" id="categoria">
        <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
        <option value="1">Estudiante</option>
        <option value="2">Trabajador</option>
    </select> 
     <div class="ayuda">
        <p> Si selecciona Estudiante, debera mosrar los grupos, en caso contrario los dpto.</p>
    </div>          
</div>

        <div class="form-group oculto" id="grupoContenedor">
            <label for="grupo" >Grupo</label>
            <select name="grupo" class="form-control" id="grupo">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
                <option value="1">1301</option>   
                <option value="2">1302</option>
                <option value="3">1303</option>   
                <option value="4">1304</option>
                <option value="5">1305</option>   
                <option value="6">CPE</option>
            </select>  
            <div class="ayuda">
                <p> Solo se muestra si se selecciona estudiante.</p>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group oculto" id="dptoContenedor">
            <label for="dpto" >Dpto.</label>
            <select name="dpto" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
                <option value="1">Programación</option>   
                <option value="2">Humanidades</option>
                <option value="3">Ciencias Básicas</option>   
            </select>    
            <div class="ayuda">
                <p> Solo se muestra si se selecciona trabajador.</p>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

Nota:

Aunque no lo comentas en tu pregunta, imagino que si el usuario elige un option pero luego cambia de idea y elige otro, querrás que se oculte el select de su primera elección y que aparezca el de su segunda elección. En ese caso, debes hacer que nada más se active el evento, se oculten todos los selects (salvo el original) y luego se muestre el de la última elección.

Esto lo harás con la línea que he comentado:

```
$('.oculto').hide();
```

Sólo tienes que descomentarla.

Comment: Revise el HTML y no sé cómo deje pasar algo como eso ‍♂️. Hice los cambios k m dijiste y funciona al . Gracias

Comment: M podrías explicar cómo funciona esta línea. $('.oculto').hide()

Comment: @CasinerO, claro. Lo que hace el método *hide* es simplemente ocultar (cambiar la propiedad *display* de css a *none*) a todos los elementos HTML a los que haga referencia el selector (el selector es lo que pones delante; en este caso: todos los elementos con clase *oculto*). 

Así pués, lo que haces en tu código es: primero esconde todos los elementos con la clase *oculto*, y ahora muestra sólo el que corresponda.

Espero que  se haya entendido bien.